# Relocating interrupt vector table using linker script

Tags: c, stm32, cortex-m, linker-scripts

I'm trying to move interrupt vector to DTCMRAM. The test code is simple blinking LED by timer interrupt.
There I've changed load adress of .isr_vector:

```
MEMORY
{
  ITCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
  FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 2048K
  DTCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  RAM_D1 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
_sivector = LOADADDR(.isr_vector);
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _svector = .;
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _evector = .;
  } >ITCMRAM AT> FLASH
```

After that I've added data copyer before main call (generated according to `.data` copier) in startup:

```
ldr r0, =_svector
  ldr r1, =_evector
  ldr r2, =_sivector
  movs r3, #0
  b LoopCopyVectorInit

CopyVectorInit:
  ldr r4, [r2, r3]
  str r4, [r0, r3]
  adds r3, r3, #4

LoopCopyVectorInit:
  adds r4, r0, r3
  cmp r4, r1
  bcc CopyVectorInit
```

Now I want to tell MCU that new vector table is availible using SCR->VTOR according to [here](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/using_VTOR_pg.html).

Then here is main code:

```
extern uint32_t _sivector;
extern uint32_t _svector;
extern uint32_t _evector;
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    __disable_irq();
      SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)*_sivector;
    __DSB();
    __enable_irq();
```

But in this way debugger shows _svector and _sivector is equal to `0x24080000` and _evector=`0x504f105`.

Code line that reinitialize VTOR causes fault. Obviously _svector and _sivector has wrong address. Why? Even by commenting `ITCMRAM AT>` the _*vector variables carry wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never work this way.

You end in the fault as when the uC boots up, it does not have the interrupt vector table at the standard place (which is required). Later you can copy and set the interrupt vector table in the place you want.

So your startup code will never be executed as the reset vector is not set to anything meaningful.

```
extern uint32_t _sivector;
extern uint32_t _svector;
extern uint32_t _evector;

void __attribute__((constructor)) copyVect(void)
{
  memcpy(&_sivector, &_svector, (&_evector - &_svector) * sizeof(uint32_t));
}


int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    __disable_irq();
      SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)&_sivector;
    __DSB();
    __enable_irq();
```

or

```
extern uint32_t _sivector[];
extern uint32_t _svector[];
extern uint32_t _evector[];

void __attribute__((constructor)) copyVect(void)
{
  memcpy(_sivector, _svector, (_evector - _svector) * sizeof(uint32_t));
}




int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    __disable_irq();
      SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)_sivector;
    __DSB();
    __enable_irq();
```

```
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _svector = .;
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _evector = .;
  } >FLASH

/* ... */

  .isr_vector_itcm :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sivector = .;
    . += _evector - _svector;
  } > ITCMRAM
```

BTW the copy in the assembly file is not needed anymore.

Comment: fault happen after `vtor` getting new values in main. before that it works.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd wrong usage of symbols

Comment: It seems yoyu don't like `startup.s` ,really? why?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd you do not need it. The same code you can write in plain C without even touching the assembler. It is one of the myths - startup has to be written in assembler. I wrote RTOS using only intrinsic and few `asm` directives

Comment: Nice, maybe your way is clearer for someone who is new to our code. And tries to understand what is going on.

Comment: Also it seems you've forgot to add AT> FLASH for `.isr_vector_itcm` section.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd no, I did not forget. It is as it has to be. I would suggest to read the `ld` documentation to understand all that magic `AT` and `>`s

Comment: I have read, > indicate VMA and AT> indicate LMA.

Answer (score 1):

So, the obvious question is, why are those values incorrect.

I think you need to take address of those variables. `SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)&_sivector`, not with asterisk. You want the address of that variable, not its content (which is undefined btw) dereferenced as a pointer and casted to uint32_t.

It's exactly the same logic with putting vars into data sections. Variables from linker scripts don't have a usable value. They're needed as address pointers, so just like you take &_stackstart or whatever you call it, similar thing should apply here.

EDIT: I've used the word "variable" a little too liberally. Linker script defines a symbol. There is no defined value associated with it.

Comment: I think their contents are adresses! They are .world or .global. I then assumed to be uint32_t

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd no they're not. They're variables. int32_t x; the value of x itself is undefined, but &x exists (provided the compiler didn't optimize it away).

Comment: They are not variables only **symbols**

Comment: yeah I misused the terminology a bit, agree, but the logic still holds true. The value of _sivector is undefined. One needs &_sivector.

Comment: Then how you interpret this: `_svector=.`. The dot is address and _svector is symbol or variable.

Comment: It's in linker script, which works differently. It's a valid statement for linker script. I can almost guarantee you that &_svector is what you're looking for. Just try it out.

Comment: @Ilya depending how they are defined in the C file. See my answer - two options

Comment: It seems you'r right, (upvote), thanks I'm searching.